# How to send response from a filter in jersey without communicating with the actual service

Tags: java, rest, service, filter, jersey

is there anyway in jersey, to send the response from the filter itself, without not even passing the request to the service.
But, it should be a proper response with some output, not throwing some exception as reply.
I'm using jersey 1.8